# drawing square net in SDI MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mfc, ondraw, sdi

how can i draw square net ( like chess) in SDI MFC ?
and how to determine the position for putting some more shape in specific position ? 
i have to use (Moveto) and (Lineto) and draw them 1 by 1 ?
or using bitmap ? or easier way ? 
i tried in this way but it's not really smart.
thank you.

```
COLORREF blueline = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    pen1.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, blueline);
    pDC->SelectObject(&pen1);
    pDC->MoveTo(0,80);
    pDC->LineTo(1024, 80);
    pDC->SelectObject(&pen1);
```

Comment: Draw into a memory DC and then blit it to the screen.

Comment: can you give me more detail ?

Comment: Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/cc308997(v=vs.90).aspx. You use the **CMemDC** class. This is good if you want to reduce flickering.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: All supported versions of Windows implement double-buffering already, as is. There hardly ever is a need to render to a memory device context.

Comment: @IInspectable I was not aware that MFC did these days. That is why I used the CMemDC and blip to screen automatically.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: This has nothing to do with MFC. MFC merely provides wrappers around standard Windows controls and windows. Those are double-buffered by default in the Desktop Window Manager (DWM).

Comment: @IInspectable But I have been taught that at times you may still do your painting in the background and then render it. Maybe not needed for this scenario. Thanks for clarification though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw solid rectangles by calling [CDC::FillSolidRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdxe16aw.aspx). If your rectangles should contain a more complex pattern, use [CDC::FillRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0421fewx.aspx) instead.

You can render a checkered board using the following pseudo-code:

```cpp
for (int x = 0; x < 8; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; ++y ) {
        // Calculate square position and size
        int x0 = x_origin + x * square_width;
        int x1 = x_origin + (x + 1) * square_width;
        int y0 = y_origin + y * square_height;
        int y1 = y_origin + (y + 1) * square_height;
        RECT r = {x0, y0, x1, y1};
        // Pick alternating color
        COLORREF color = (x + y) & 1 ? RGB(0, 0, 0) : RGB(255, 255, 255);
        // Render square
        pDC->FillSolidRect(&r, color);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Emadsharifmohseny: Since that is what you asked for, I don't see why you are surprised. Those are the ingredients for a checkered chess board. If that is not fancy enough, I also linked to an API that can fill rectangles with arbitrarily complex patterns.

Comment: @IInspectable I think he is asking how to construct the "Net" itself of "Squares".

Comment: i am trying to make net , not just hatches

Comment: i think you didnt catch my meaning , btw thanks for help

Comment: @Emadsharifmohseny: I can only answer the question that was asked. If you want something *"like chess"*, and the answer that's offering something *"like chess"* doesn't address your question, then you have meant to ask a different question than you did. If you are looking for a grid, the `MoveTo` and `LineTo` are the calls to use.